# Visual Studio 2005/2008 IDE (auto-select file in solution explorer)

Tags: visual-studio

I have some very big solutions (lots of projects, lots of files). I was wondering if it's possible that when selecting a document from the open documents (navigating through the tabs) the current file would be selected in the solution explorer tree view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing the Solution Explorer to select the file in the editor in visual studio 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163/forcing-the-solution-explorer-to-select-the-file-in-the-editor-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There you go: [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jannemattila/archive/2009/02/21/visual-studio-2008-track-active-item-in-solution-explorer.aspx)

Comment: Just what i needed. Didn't even hope to be that easy.

Answer (score 8):

Tools → Options → Projects And Solutions → Track Active Item In Solution Explorer