# VS 2010 - Track the active item in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My Visual Studio 2010 has a checked CheckBox "Track active in Solution Explorer". There's a ReSharper intalles as well. So sometimes VS doesn't track the current the current item in Solution Explorer. But sometimes does.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about your particular problem.

Visual Studio 2012 (just out today) has a new shortcut `Ctrl [, S`. Yes you have to type `Ctrl [` and then release and then type `S`. It will synchronize to the item.

Usually this is more useful than always tracking.

Answer (score 3):

if you're using Resharper with the Visual Studio mapping you can use `Shift+Alt+L` to synchronize the current file in the solution explorer